# Strange logo on the frame

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

I just bought this bike, but it seems like the frame is not Bianchi, all marks and texts are stickers. Also, there are quite a few logos on the frame. Does anyone know which frame this is?

Thanks!

[image: logo on the frame]

[image: frame]

Comment: Is there a serial number on the bottom bracket?

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking it looks a lot like the Hans Lutz logo:

[image]

German manufacturer, ex racer...

I'm not sure he made just lugs, for Bianchi at that. So I think you're correct about it being rebranded. Silly really, the Hans Lutz I've seen is nice stuff!

Note the color of the frame too, very similar to that pictured. I can also vouch that the bidon holder mount holes on yours look exactly the same as those on the frame pictured here.

Answer (score 0):

Initially I thought this was an Olmo but it looks like Japanese bike frame builder 3RENSHO.

You can see some on Google or here: https://www.flickr.com/photos/39068621@N08/4620234666